# Reload SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new to Android Prorgramming and have a problem understandig SharedPreferences.
I have a Main Activity and a Settings Activity.
I want to be able to change a SharedPreference (here called firstWaitTime) in the Settings Activity and work with it in the Main Activity.
I can Set the new value in the settings, but in the Main Activity i only see the new value when i close and reopen the app.

I Think i would need a OnPrefrenceChanged Listender but i have no idea how to implement it...

**The Main one looks like this:**

```html
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //Radio Button
    private int stufe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int firstWaitTime = settings.getInt("firstWaitTime", 12);
        int secondWaitTime = settings.getInt("secondWaitTime", 8);
        int thirdWaitTime = settings.getInt("thirdWaitTime", 6);

        //TEST
        final TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
        test.setText("" + firstWaitTime);

}
```

**The Settings Activity looks like this:**

```html
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

 final SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE);

//BUTTON

        final EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        Button save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtn);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                //---save the values in the EditText view to preferences---
                editor.putInt("firstWaitTime", Integer.parseInt(edit1.getText().toString()));

                //---saves the values---
                editor.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: on `onResume` of the activity get the shared preference value again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreate()` will not be called as Android hasn't killed the Activity. Try putting your code in `onResume()` instead. For more info read up on [the  Android Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: thank you so i'll have to insert the complete code in the onCreate in the onResume if i understand this right....i'll try